# Can't connect to MySQL database using Coda 2

Tags: mysql, database, ssh, raspberry-pi, coda

I am hosting a website on a Raspberry Pi that has a MySQL server running.

Using Terminal on Mac, I can remotely ssh into the RPi and then connect to the server.

I am trying to remotely connect to the server using Coda 2, but it doesn't seem to be working. I chose the 'via SSH' option, using the following details:

[image]

(I've removed my login details)

However, using the exact same details with SequelPro, it works just fine?

[image]

What is going on here? Why is it not working for Coda?

Comment: Maybe the ssh port shouldn't be 22 like in your first image? Maybe this port it is closed by your firewall.

Comment: @thescion no, he states that he can use ssh to log in, only with the application it doesn't work.

Comment: Is there any error you get when trying to connect? Any logs from Coda, any logs from the server?

Comment: Coda just says SSH connection Failed! The SSH Tunnel has unexpectedly closed.

Comment: i hate mysql though SSH why don't you just create a user on the mysql sever for coda and use the normall socket connection method, you can even create the mysql user to only work on 192.168.1.* host so it can only be logged in from your lan?

Comment: Are you finally connected to MySQL via SSH. I have the same situation and i can't connect.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue with Coda 2. I'm going to assume you're using SSH keys, if not please elaborate.

Open `~/.ssh/config`, you'll need to use `sudo vim/nano/emacs` because its a protected file. Then add these two lines:

```
Host 192.168.1.108
IdentityFile /the/path/to/your/ssh/key
```

This asserts the identification of the SSH key.

Reference to the Coda docs: [here](https://library.panic.com/general/key-based-authentication/)

Answer (score -1):

Please use server as 192.168.1.108 (your server ip address) not 127.0.0.1

Thanks